# Use PC as an external monitor when remoting into it

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

so... I have a laptop (A) for work.   I also have a big main Mac (B) at home with a 43" main monitor, and a few others attached.

I use (A) by remoting into it, because I can do all the things like slack, zoom, mail etc on the outer machine, and just do actual code editing and compiling on (A).  And very important point - I want (A) as a window on the large monitor, because when I use it it is the focus.

However... It bothers me that the laptop (A) just sits there showing a screen and the time while I'm remoting into it.   Seems a waste - I want to use it - and it seems it *should* be possible to punt the RDP session to the background somehow.

What I really want is to use one of the many pieces of software that turn that screen into an external monitor for my Mac - so somehow I want to put the RDP session into the background, or run the monitor software over the top of it or something.  I've heard of RDP wrapper, so going to give that a go, but wondering if anyone has a solution for something like that?

what I'm **not looking for** - is any of the many bits of software, like mouse without borders, that allow you to **control that machine** - because when I'm using that machine, I want it front and centre maximized in 4k goodness.... not turning my head to do work on a tiny laptop screen.    I absolutely want to be RDP-ing into it.  I also don't want a KVM - I was using one before, then realised it's much better to be able to be using the machines at the same time with RDP, rather than having to switch between them.

any ideas would be appreciated (thx)

Comment: To clarify you want to remote into your laptop from your Mac, while at the same time extending your Mac's display onto the screen of that same laptop since the laptop screen isn't needed by the laptop while you are remoting into it?

Comment: yes - exactly that.

Comment: I can't imagine it will make sense to continue down this path.  If you simply put your laptop out of your way you can add another cheap (or not) much bigger screen to your MAC & continue to  remote into your laptop on your MAC, You can manage how much of the two screens' real estate you want to use for the RDP session at any time.  A laptop is not usually designed to support additional hw display inputs, & your use case is unlikely to have enough traction that anyone has bothered solving it within Windows itself when there are so many other approaches and use cases.